# Data frame error when using anovaVCA() function

Tags: r, precision, anova

I am trying to run a two-way ANOVA using the VCA() function from the library "VCA". The dataframe (named "results") I am running this analysis on is:

```
Group | F/L | Prep | result
1         F      1       306
1         F      1       300
1         F      2       319
1         F      2       314
1         F      3       317
1         F      3       306
1         L      1       322
1         L      1       306
1         L      2       314
1         L      2       316
1         L      3       327
1         L      3       316
```

and the actual code I am running is `anovaVCA(result ~ F\L+Prep, Data = result)`. When I do this I get the error code:

```
Error in anovaVCA(result ~ `F/L` + Prep, Data = results) : 
  identical(class(Data), "data.frame") is not TRUE
```

I have tried googling this error code but I admit I don't really understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Function anovaVCA() cannot deal with variable names containing special characters as in "F/L". Backticks will not work. If you rename it to e.g. "FL" it should work.

```
> dat
   Group FL Prep result
1      1  F    1    306
2      1  F    1    300
3      1  F    2    319
4      1  F    2    314
5      1  F    3    317
6      1  F    3    306
7      1  L    1    322
8      1  L    1    306
9      1  L    2    314
10     1  L    2    316
11     1  L    3    327
12     1  L    3    316

> anovaVCA(result ~ FL + Prep, Data = dat)
Convert variable Prep from "character" to "factor"!
Convert variable FL from "character" to "factor"!


Result Variance Component Analysis:
-----------------------------------

  Name  DF       SS         MS        VC        %Total    SD       CV[%]   
1 total 6.357803                      68.208333 100       8.258834 2.633697
2 FL    1        126.75     126.75    13.25     19.425779 3.640055 1.160793
3 Prep  2        156.166667 78.083333 7.708333  11.301161 2.776389 0.885375
4 error 8        378        47.25     47.25     69.27306  6.873864 2.192037

Mean: 313.5833 (N = 12) 

Experimental Design: balanced  |  Method: ANOVA
```